# Best way of splitting a string and create the following array: '1-2-3' -> ['1', '1-2', '1-2-3']

Tags: javascript

the string is something like this:

```
const string = '1-2-3-4-5-6-7-...-n';
```

and I need an array like this:

```
const arr = ['1', '1-2', '1-2-3', '1-2-3-4', '1-2-...-n'];
```

I have go into this so far:

```
const str = '1-2-3'; 
const arr = []; let actualValue = '';
const splitArray = str.split('-');
for (let i = 0; i < splitArray.length; i++) {
  if (actualValue)         
    actualValue = actualValue + '-' + splitArray[i];     
  else 
    actualValue = splitArray[i];
  
  arr.push(actualValue); 
}
```

Comment: What exactly isn't working? If i run this in fiddle it does give the desired result
[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/yof82L0v/)

Comment: I was wondering if there's a better way of doing it

Comment: Your solution is the simpliest - it is very clear and easy to understand. As a new programmer - that is the best thing imo. Oleg provided other solution as an answer, but it's harder to understand since you will have to know what all the additional functions do (like `reduce`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this solution will suit you?

```js
const result = "1-2-3-4-5-6-7-8-9".split("-").reduce((prev, curr) => {
  const last = prev.slice(-1);
  last.push(curr);
  prev.push(last.join("-"));
  return prev;
}, []);
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

I prefer

```js
const str = '1-2-3'; 
const arr = []; let actualValue = '';
const splitArray = str.split('-');
if (splitArray.length) {
  actualValue = splitArray[0];
  arr.push(actualValue);
}

for (let i = 1; i < splitArray.length; i++) {
  actualValue = actualValue + '-' + splitArray[i];
  
  arr.push(actualValue); 
}

console.log(arr);
```

to reduce the number of comparisons.